# Integral of a two-valued function with two branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Is it possible to calculate in closed-form the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{sinc}(\sqrt{1+x^4})\,dx$ (sinc being the cardinal sine, $\sin(x)/x$)?

The function is everywhere defined (all singularities are removable) and its complex version has, I think, two branch cuts, which seem to be the reason for my difficulties. They can be chosen for integrating along the real line as the intervals $[z_1,z_2]$ and $[z_3,z_4]$, $[z_1,z_4]$ and $[z_2,z_3]$ or $[z_1,z_3]$ and $[z_2,z_4]$, where $z_k=e^{ik\pi/4}$). The integral would then seem to involve two dog-bones contour or reduce to calculate $\int_0^1\mathrm{sinc}(\sqrt{1-x^4})dx$ which doesn't bring me anywhere.

The fact that all residues are zero, including the one at infinity, while the integral is not, seems to suggest my attempts through exterior domains in the complex plane is intrinsically flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the answer is not very pretty. By simply setting $\sqrt{1+x^4}=u$, then exploiting Laplace transforms, we get:

> $$ I = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin u}{(u^2-1)^{3/4}}\,du =2^{3/4}\sqrt{\pi}\, J_{\frac{1}{4}}(1)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)=2.0324503\ldots$$

where $J_{\frac{1}{4}}$ is a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: Thanks, I find that the result is actually very pretty. Actually I'm interested in the Fourier transform of this function, which I believe is trivially related to the solution of the above problems through residues, if that would work. I couldn't use your Laplace method though, that works so splendidly for the concrete question I asked, since it brings me to a convolution of two complicated functions (Bessels & imaginary error function) when I bring back the complex integral. I've posted another question laying out the full problem: see http://goo.gl/i4NTbX